# jQuery, not $(this) along with other things (in a comma separated list)

Tags: jquery

Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong when trying to put $(this) in a comma separated list, e.g....

This works....

```
$('#nav').hover(function(){
    $('body > :not(.test)).hide();
    $('.test').appendTo('body');
)};
```

But when I add 'this' it does NOT work...

```
$('#nav').hover(function(){
    $('body > :not(.test)', this).hide();
    $('.test', this).appendTo('body');
)};
```

I'm trying to say "Don't hide .test and also don't hide this", can you suggest how to modify my code to do this? Many thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Setting something like `$(".myclass", obj)` will find selectors of `.myclass` within the context of `obj`. Is this the intention?

Comment: Also on an unrelated note, you are missing a `'` on your first code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [second argument to jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) is a context in which the selector will be searched for. In your case, you're trying to find a `body` element inside `this`, which is whatever `#nav` is, and that is unlikely to have a `body` element as a descendant.

Also I'm assuming it's just a typo in the question but your first example won't work either because you're missing the closing quote on the `body > :not(.test)` selector.

**Update** based on comments

To also exclude `this` from a selection you could use the [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method instead of the `:not` selector:

```
$('body > :not(.test)').not(this).hide();
```

I think your second line is attempting to append `.nav-news` and `this` to `body`, in which case you want the opposite of the `not` method, which is [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
$(".nav-news").add(this).appendTo("body");
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, I'm trying to say "Don't hide .test and also don't hide this", can you suggest how to modify my code to do this? Many thanks

Comment: @SparrwHawk - See my edit. You should be able to use the `not` method instead of the `:not` selector.

Comment: Thanks James, I think we're almost there, I have this now...

    `$('#nav').hover(function(){
          `$('body > :not(.test)').not(this).hide();
        `$('.test'), $(this).appendTo('body');
    `)};

What's happening is $(this) is staying visible but .test is not reappearing, any ideas?

Comment: What is the 2nd line meant to do? Append `.nav-news` and `this` to `body`?

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter instead of shift + enter so it entered my unfinished comment.

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I wanted, it works. Many thanks for your patience :-)

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

The `this` in this instance means that the selected elements should be inside of "`this`", as in, inside of the hovered element.

I seriously doubt that a direct child of `body` can still be inside of `#nav` now can it? :)